# Generate ListItems within a repeater

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have an ASP.NET repeater that is loading up shirts for purchase.  The data is stored in an XML file, and I have the available shirt sizes in a comma delimited format, so one shirt is S,M,L, another is S,M,L,XL.

Since Im using a repeater, I was trying to perform the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSize" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Choose" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<% For Each s As String In XPath("Sizes").Split(",")
  Me.ddlSize.Items.Add(New ListItem(s, s))
Next %>
```

I receive the error that ddlSize is not a member of the page, so I assume the drop down list just isn't in scope?  Anyway, what is the best way to generate list items in a repeater?  Thanks!

EDIT 1 - Per a comment, my XML is structured as follows:

```
<product>
    <name>Golf Shirt</name>
    <description>Nike branded</description>
    <cost>49.99</cost>
    <sizes>S,M,L,XL</sizes>
</product>
```

Comment: show me how the xml is structured and I can help you. Just show one shirt or something.

Comment: Thanks @C.Hazelton just added a sample structure!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. You want to display the sizes in a Repeater? Or do you want to display the sizes in a DropDownList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposed answers were helpful, but ultimately not useful for my scenario, since it entailed having to re-read through the datasource, and then find a method to track "which product" I was currently trying to load.

In the end, I was able to use the ItemDataBound event for my listview, find my dropdownlist control, and use the DataBinder.Eval function to parse my data and add the items.  Code sample is below, for any who are curious.

```
If e.Item.FindControl("ddlSize") IsNot Nothing Then
    'Get our dropdownlist
    Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlSize"), DropDownList)
        'Make sure we didn't already add items to this ctrl
        If ddl.Items.Count = 0 Then
            'get our sizes, which are stored in comma delimited format
            Dim sizes() As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Sizes").ToString.Split(",")
            'add our items
            For Each s As String In sizes
                ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem(s, s))
            Next
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you'll need to do. Add this to your code behind. Assuming you are using c# but if not you can convert this easily (just google c# to vb). I wouldn't do this in the page but rather in code behind. Also your sample xml does not have a key of any sort unless you are using the "name" node which btw is a bad idea. I would suggest you consider changing the xml to the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products>
<product id="1">
  <name>Golf Shirt</name>
  <description>Nike branded</description>
  <cost>49.99</cost>
  <sizes>S,M,L,XL</sizes>
 </product>
 <product id="2">
  <name>Another Golf Shirt</name>
  <description>Ashworth branded</description>
  <cost>59.99</cost>
  <sizes>S,M,L,XL,XXL</sizes>
 </product>
</products>
```

What happens below is when the control is loaded it grabs the xml doc and then using your key (most likely you'll be on a product page and it will have some key, if not use the "name" node but again be careful with that) selects the single node. We take the sizes and trim/replace to make sure we don't have extra spaces and so on. When then add each from the string array to the dropdown.

```
  protected void ddlSize_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // get reference to dropdown
            var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

            // clear existing items if not it will keep appending.
            ddl.Items.Clear();

            // add default choose item.
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Choose", ""));

            // get the xml document.
            var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/items.xml");
            xDoc.Load(path);

            // you'll want to get this id from a param from your page or something.
            // this is because I'm assuming you'll have several products you'll need to grab
            // the product but the "name" node or an attribute as I've added called "id" or something.
            var id = 1;

            // select the sizes node based on our id as described above.
            var node = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//product[@id='" + id + "']//sizes");

            // split to string array but trim and replace any spaces just in case.
            string[] sizes = node.InnerText.ToString().Trim().Replace(" ", "").Split(',');

            // iterate sizes and add them to the drop down.
            foreach (string s in sizes)
            {
                ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(s, s));
            }
        }            

    }
```

BTW this may seem like a lot but its not really. You could investigate some helper methods/extensions that you'd put in a helper class and that would clean up each dropdown etc that you need this will. You could also depending on the size of the xml doc cache it etc but that's another topic.

Comment: Thanks for the help @origin1tech, but in the end this solution wasn't just quite right for me, I just posted my solution below.   Do appreciate the help however, all the best..

Comment: Glad it put you in the right direction. Ultimately on my end I don't have all the info so my intent as do most is to give you the general idea. Often the complete solution cannot be provided as we just don't have all the info. Lastly you may want to also investigate .net MVC and WebApi. Many devs are opting for them over webforms. I'd be remiss if I didn't mention it. best of luck.